# Duplicate comments in chatrooms from users with poor connections

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, connectivity

Here on my beach in Romania with my decaying HP netbook I often have a lousy connection yet I still like to spend time in Stack Exchange chatrooms.

But when my connection gets sketchy I often get the `retry/cancel` message in chat when something I said failed to go through. So I trust it and click it. Sometimes I start to get a series of posts that didn't go through all prompting. Sometimes I have to retry many times before they go through.

But then when the connection gets a bit more reliable I see that more than one of my comments went through:

[image: duplicate messages in chatroom] <sup>[link to stuttering chat ...](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5975220#5975220)</sup>

This makes me think some of the code which decides whether to show the `retry/cancel` prompt is in fact detached from the code which detects whether in fact a post from a user was successfully sent to the server.

I'm sure there can be some tricky race conditions and timeouts firing just before an Ajax call responds etc. But hey a bug is a bug. Can't you also check for duplicate messages if not all the time then at least after issuing the `retry/cancel` prompt?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were just spamming. Sorry. :D

Answer (score 4):

> This makes me think some of the code which decides whether to show the retry/cancel prompt is in fact detached from the code which detects whether in fact a post from a user was successfully sent to the server.

This is just wrong. But this being HTTP, the question "Has the server received the message?" can only be answered by "Have we received the server's confirmation?", and obviously this has to happen in a reasonable time. We could increase this timeout, which may benefit your awful connection, but would make things worse for everyone else, because it means they would only be notified after (say) a whole minute if the message they sent got lost.

> Can't you also check for duplicate messages if not all the time then at least after issuing the retry/cancel prompt?

We *do* check for duplicate messages posted to the same room within 20 seconds. I guess that's a number we can increase a bit; there's really no reason to deliberately post the same message twice in succession into the same room within, say, one minute.

But seriously, at some point you'll have to consider that maybe with such a bad connection, a realtime chat application may not be the best thing to be running.

Comment: Are you telling me I'm holding it wrong? (-;

Comment: if iD Software got QuakeWorld running as smooth as they did on crappy 14.4 modem connections, no reason "realtime" chat should not work... IIR IRC worked on less

Comment: @mxmissile There's a difference between a slow connection and a bad connection.

Comment: @hippietrail Worth a try holding it differently :)

Comment: @balpha any chance to raise the bar to one minute then, as you mentioned? This appears to still happen to people...

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled on to this bug myself, talking with the very same @hippietrail no less.

[image]

You can see me explaining I saw the bug, then it happened again.

The only thing I have to add to the previous comments is that all the other real time chats work just fine. I am aware that maybe the connection from me to the SE-chat server is that little bit worse than the other apps servers, and therefore they work. But on the other hand I have noticed that skype just retries on its own and so far google talk has never produced any repeated messages no matter how screwed up my connection.

I am a frequent user of mobile devices in countries like Malaysia and Thailand where even a landline is questionable when it comes to reliability. But facebook chat, irc, skype and so on works for everyone

Awesome chat(s) btw even with some minor minor stuff like this ^^

Comment: I can see now that it's contagious and I'm the vector. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @hippietrail lol, yes you're the vector.

Answer (score 2):

This happens a lot to me also. I'm on a 3G connection in rural India. Bulk transfer speed is alright (like 400 kilobytes per second), but initial contact with servers can be pretty slow to establish. The issue seems to vary for different websites. SE is pretty tough. For example, it can take ten seconds to open the notification or achievements bar. Due to these conditions, I frequently experience the chat bug described in the question.

[image]